# Can I use system() in iOS?

Tags: ios, system

I wanna see all the running processed using `system("ps x");` or a similar function.. Then `kill` unwanted processes using `system("kill xxxx");`.. is it possible in iOS?

Comment: On jailbroken devices, or for shipping apps in the App Store? ("probably", and "no way", respectively)

Comment: What do you mean? On your personal device only? The OS has capabilities to free RAM by killing background processes already that should be transparent to you. I can't conceive of why you would want to do this manually. And why can't you try the `system` calls and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible for security reasons. Being able to access so much information would allow for others to re-image the device.

Comment: any other ways to free up ram?