# Why Android decide to keep Runtime.exec()?

Tags: android

The equivalent function call in iOS is `system()`, whereas Apple explicitly states that an app wishing to be on the App Store cannot use this function due to security issue ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726355/can-i-use-system-in-ios)). It would not be hard to imagine that some may use this to do some crazy things, which lead me to ask why Google doesn't just simply remove `Runtime.exec()`, or override its functionality?

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer Team X make Decision Y" are not well-suited for Stack Overflow. The only people likely to be able to answer the question definitively are the members of Developer Team X, and they are unlikely to be answering questions here. All anyone else can do is offer opinions.

Comment: From your link, I suppose your question is more like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-on-android

Comment: By the way: are you sure using system() in iOS is not allowed? I've found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4733885/2057480

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in Google Play we haven't got any real review process. No one checks application before publishing. In that situation there is no difference if `Runtime.exec()` is allowed or not.

In the past in Google Play there was also a limit to 50MB per APK. In that situation in some applications which use large graphical library (e.g. Unity 3D engine + native large project) using a runtime library was the only option to be under 50MB limit. It is of course not the official reason, but you can see that `Runtime.exec()` can be useful.

Comment: Apps have been reviewed by tools as part of the Play Store submission process for a few years.

Comment: Of course it's true. But Apple review process is much more strict than Google's one.